# Creating a shortcut or a script in Ubuntu

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, shortcut-file

I just installed Ubuntu (switched from Windows) and I need some sort of an easy way to execute a program with additional arguments.

From the terminal, I'd do this:

```
/home/steam/steamcmd +login anonymous +force_install_dir /home/steam/css/ +app_update 232330 +quit
```

Is there a way to make it easier, so I can just double click a shortcut or write something like `css_update` into my console?

Notice that `steam` is a custom account created with `sudo useradd steam` and I don't have permissions to even create a shortcut with the file manager inside the `steam` directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a shell script.

Create the file in your home directory. You can use `vim` or any other text editor.

`vim css_update`

Press `i` to activate insert mode and paste the following (`Ctrl-Shift-V` to paste in a console):

```
#!/bin/bash
/home/steam/steamcmd +login anonymous +force_install_dir /home/steam/css/ +app_update 232330 +quit
```

Enter `:wq` to write and quit.

Make the file exeutable:

`sudo chmod +x css_update`

To run it from your home directory:

`./css_update`

Comment: I don't use vim so I tried gedit instead: `steam@Tron100:~$ touch css_update 
steam@Tron100:~$ gedit css_update
No protocol specified

** (gedit:11271): WARNING **: Could not open X display
No protocol specified
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.

(gedit:11271): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0`

Comment: Are you remotely connected to your server? Maybe try `nano` or `vi`.

Comment: Okay I managed to write the file using `nano`, but now I get this `steam@Tron100:~$ ./update_css
-su: ./update_css: Permission denied`

Comment: I see you renamed the file to `update_css` instead of `css_update`. Did you `chmod +x update_css`? Do a `ll update_css` and see if it has the `x` permission

Comment: Yeah I did. Here's teh result of `ll update_css`:  `-rwxrwxr-x 1 steam steam 112 march 15 15:56 update_css*`

Comment: It says user **steam**? Aren't you executing the original command with your own user? Because if that's the case then `update_css` should be in your home directory and owned by your user.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73016/discussion-between-aergistal-and-skamah-one).

Comment: I'm sorry, I had to take a break from the computer. But I got the problem fixed, I just switched my user to `steam` from the gui (from the system/power button on the top right corner) and it all worked perfect.